# Using Stash pagination links and need cleaner URL's

Tags: stash, url, pagination, links

Using the pagination feature in stash something like this:

```
{exp:stash:get_list
    name="sv_blogs_post_list"
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_conditionals="yes"
    process="end"
    prefix="st_pre"
    limit="{stash:list_limit}"
    paginate="bottom"
}

    {!-- THE PAGINATION --}
    {st_pre:paginate}
        {pagination_links}
            {previous_page}<a href="{pagination_url}" class="btn btn-brick flat">Previous Post</a>{/previous_page}
            {next_page}<a href="{pagination_url}" class="btn btn-brick flat pull-right">Next Post</a>{/next_page}
        {/pagination_links}
    {/st_pre:paginate}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

The problem is that the URL stays with the `{url_title}` of whatever the initial blog post read was. Is there a way to use the next and previous to actually link to the true link?

---

*** UPDATE ***

I decided to use the `{exp:channel:next_entry}` and `{exp:channel:prev_entry}` per a suggestion from @croxton. Now I have this:

```
{exp:channel:prev_entry
    url_title="{segment_2}"
    channel="blog_post"
}
    <a href='{path="blog"}' class='btn flat'>Previous Post</a>{/exp:channel:prev_entry}
{exp:channel:next_entry
    url_title="{segment_2}"
    channel="blog_post"
}
    <a href='{path="blog"}' class='btn flat pull-right'>Next Post</a>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}
```

NOW the issue is stash keeping the same variables on the page when it directs to the new link...

Current Page:
`http://my-site.com/blog/article-3`

Previous Link:
`http://my-site.com/blog/article-2/`

Next Link:
`http://my-site.com/blog/article-4`

That is working great... However, the page content is keeping the stashed values for elements like  `<div class="title">{st_pre:sv_bp_title}</div>`.

That sits inside my `{exp:stash:get_list}` which is set like this:

```
{exp:stash:get_list
    name="sv_blogs_post_list"
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_conditionals="yes"
    process="end"
    prefix="st_pre"
    limit="{stash:list_limit}"
    paginate="bottom"
}
```

All of those are being set in a data template like this:

```
    {exp:stash:set_list name="sv_blogs_post_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="{stash:channel}"
            dynamic="{stash:dynamic}"
            orderby="{stash:order_by}"
            status="{stash:status}"
            limit="{stash:limit}"
            paginate="{stash:paginate}"
        }
            {stash:sv_bp_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:sv_bp_entry_id}
            {stash:sv_bp_entry_date}{entry_date format="%m.%d.%Y"}{/stash:sv_bp_entry_date}
            {stash:sv_bp_relative_time}{relative_date}{/stash:sv_bp_relative_time}
            {stash:sv_bp_author}{author}{/stash:sv_bp_author}
            {stash:sv_bp_screen_name}{screen_name}{/stash:sv_bp_screen_name}
            {stash:sv_bp_title}{title}{/stash:sv_bp_title}
            {stash:sv_bp_url_title}{url_title}{/stash:sv_bp_url_title}
            {stash:sv_bp_url_title_path}{url_title_path='blog'}{/stash:sv_bp_url_title_path}
            {stash:sv_bp_blog_copy}{blog_copy}{/stash:sv_bp_blog_copy}
            {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="sv_bp_header_images_{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
                {header_image}
                    {stash:sv_bp_header_image}{image:url:slider}{/stash:sv_bp_header_image}
                    {stash:sv_bp_header_image_original}{image:url}{/stash:sv_bp_header_image_original}
                    {stash:sv_bp_header_image_title}{image:title}{/stash:sv_bp_header_image_title}
                {/header_image}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Am I missing a tag in my set or get for stash???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Croxton (Twitter) and Sam Royama (Skype) for the help with this one. Mark got me going with the Prev/Next entry solution. Sam helped me realize my rookie mistake of not accepting a `url_title` parameter in my `set_list`.   GRRRRR

So... In the last block of code from the OP, I needed to add the `url_title` like this:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="sv_blogs_post_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="{stash:channel}"
        dynamic="{stash:dynamic}"
        orderby="{stash:order_by}"
        status="{stash:status}"
        limit="{stash:limit}"
        paginate="{stash:paginate}"

        url_title="{stash:url_title}"

    }
        ...
```